# Can't figure out why this won't work (PHP)

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I am working on an `admin` panel feature in `PHP 5.6` and whenever I try to switch a user to Admin it will set them to Builder I have no idea where or what I am doing wrong
Here is the code

this is `updateusera.php`

```
     <?php include 'core/init.php';


$id   = $_GET['id'];
$type   = $_GET['type'];

if($type == 'admin'){
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `type` = 'user' WHERE `user_id` = '$id'");
     header('location: changeusers.php');

} else if($type =='user'){
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `type` = 'admin' WHERE `user_id` = '$id'");
    header('location: changeusers.php');

}
```

//=========================================================================

```
if($type == 'moderator'){
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `type` = 'user' WHERE `user_id` = '$id'");
     header('location: changeusers.php');

} else if($type =='user'){
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `type` = 'moderator' WHERE `user_id` = '$id'");
    header('location: changeusers.php');

}
```

//=========================================================================

```
if($type == 'builder'){
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `type` = 'user' WHERE `user_id` = '$id'");
     header('location: changeusers.php');

} else if($type =='user'){
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `type` = 'builder' WHERE `user_id` = '$id'");
    header('location: changeusers.php');

}
?>

this is the changeusers.php file
```

http://pastebin.com/qR2VybTk

for some reason it would not let me put both of my codes in here  P.S I am new to Stackoverflow so i'm still getting use to all this

if anyone has an idea I would love to hear it

Thanks!

Comment: FIrst, you got two major issues. 1. You're using the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions (deprecated since PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7). 2. You're wide open for [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). I would recommend changing to Mysqli or, preferred, PDO and then use Prepared Statements.

Comment: simple question from me. what did you get when you `echo $_GET['type']`

Comment: i'm still getting use to PHP first so I am building this to get better at it and I also have a lot of other files so when i ever get the time i'll start converting to the mysqli

Comment: Btw.. you need to have `exit;` after your `header('location: ....);` statements.

Comment: You should actually start by changing to MySQLi or PDO as the first thing you do. The `mysql_`-functions are really insecure and the more code you write with those, the more you will have to update later (...and that will most likely happen then). _Don't start learning with tools that are insecure and deprecated_. It won't help you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We would love to help you out, but your question is quite vague and makes it difficult for others to easily catch on. Could you perhaps change your question in a way that makes the solution more generally applicable? Remember that one of the guidelines for a good question is to present evidence that you have done your research and have already attempted to narrow down the cause of the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three `else if` statements which is `true` when `$type =='user'`. Everything in these `else if` executing and three queries send, last of them set type builder.

You need to pass in parameters type which you need to set. That way:

```
if($type == 'admin') {
    echo "<a href='updateusera.php?id=&type=user'>Revoke Admin </a>";
} else {
    echo "<a href='updateusera.php?id=$id&type=admin'>Grant Admin </a>";
}
if($type == 'moderator') {
    echo "<a href='updateusera.php?id=$id&type=user'>Revoke Moderator </a>";
} else {
    echo "<a href='updateusera.php?id=$id&type=moderator'>Grant Moderator </a>";
}
if($type == 'builder') {
    echo "<a href='updateusera.php?id=$id&type=user'>Revoke Builder</a>";
} else {
    echo "<a href='updateusera.php?id=$id&type=builder'>Grant Builder</a>";
}
```

Then you code need to be like that:

```
if($type == 'user') {
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `type` = 'user' WHERE `user_id` = '$id'");
    header('location: changeusers.php');
    exit;
}
if($type == 'admin') {
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `type` = 'admin' WHERE `user_id` = '$id'");
    header('location: changeusers.php');
    exit;
}
if($type == 'builder') {
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `type` = 'builder' WHERE `user_id` = '$id'");
    header('location: changeusers.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: so what should I change my `else if's` to?

Comment: i added the exit's

Comment: now i'm getting `
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\updateusera.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: type in C:\xampp\htdocs\updateusera.php on line 5`

Comment: Does your code looks like `mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `type` = 'builder' WHERE `user_id` = '$id'");
    header('location: changeusers.php'); exit;`

Comment: ok so now instead of setting users to builder all the time now it sets them to admin x.x

Comment: do i need an `exit;` after every statement or no?

Answer (score 0):

You want to change your `else if` statements to if statements; Basically all the `else if` statements are being executed and the last `else if` statement is set to builder.

Comment: What should I set them to?